# ngX async assertion not getting correct expectation

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

No matter what I expect in an async assertion the test always passes. Furthermore no log is displayed when calling `console.log` after the `then` statement. My code looks as follows..

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing'
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing'
import { HttpModule, XHRBackend } from '@angular/http'
import { MockBackend } from '@angular/http/testing'
import { ApiService } from '../../client/services/api.service '
import { SocketService } from '../../client/services/socket.service'
import { EventService } from '../../client/services/event.service'
import { DirectMessageComponent } from '../../client/components/messages/direct.component'
import { SharedModule } from '../../client/components/common/shared.module'

describe('DirectMessageComponent', () => {
  // High order variables
  let comp
  let fixture

  // Asynchronous beforeEach
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    // Configure the test bed
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ SharedModule, HttpModule, RouterTestingModule ],
      declarations: [ DirectMessageComponent ],
      providers: [
        ApiService,
        SocketService,
        EventService,
        { provide: XHRBackend, useClass: MockBackend }
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents() // compile template and css
  }))

  // Synchronous beforeEach
  beforeEach(() => {
    // Assignments
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DirectMessageComponent)
    comp = fixture.componentInstance

    // Detect changes which fires ngOnInit
    fixture.detectChanges()
  })

  it('should get messages', async(() => {
    fixture.whenStable()
      .then(() => {
        expect(comp.message.length).toBeGreaterThan(0)
      })
  }))

})
```

Interestingly it fails when executed with the `fakeAsync` method, even with the proper call to `tick()`.